# Django manage.py 1.6.11 suddenly crashes when importing settings

Tags: python, django

I have an old DJango application that used work fine but suddenly crashes. I use to test it with:

```
cd /opt/formshare/src/formshare/
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/opt/formshare/src/formshare
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=formshare.settings.default_settings
python manage.py validate
```

But now I get this error:

```
(formshare) bash-4.3$ python manage.py validate
Your environment is:"formshare.settings.default_settings"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/formshare/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/formshare/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/formshare/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
  File "/opt/formshare/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 107, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/opt/formshare/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/opt/formshare/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/opt/formshare/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'formshare.settings.default_settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): cannot import name OrderedDict
```

I am using:

```
virtualenv=15.0.2
Python=2.7.11
amqp==2.1.1
billiard==3.3.0.23
celery==3.1.15
dict2xml==1.3
Django==1.6.11
django-braces==1.10.0
django-celery==3.1.16
django-cors-headers==0.13
django-db-readonly==0.3.2
django-digest==1.13
django-filter==0.7
django-guardian==1.2.4
django-nose==1.4.2
django-oauth-toolkit==0.7.2
django-registration-redux==1.1
django-reversion==1.8.4
django-taggit==0.12.1
django-templated-email==0.4.9
djangorestframework==2.4.3
djangorestframework-csv==1.3.3
dpath==1.2.post70
elaphe==0.5.6
FormEncode==1.3.1
gdata==2.0.18
httmock==1.2.2
httplib2==0.9
jdcal==1.3
jsonfield==0.9.23
kombu==4.0.0
librabbitmq==1.5.2
linecache2==1.0.0
lxml==3.4.0
Markdown==2.5
mock==1.0.1
modilabs-python-utils==0.1.5
nose==1.3.7
numpy==1.11.2
oauthlib==2.0.1
openpyxl==2.0.5
pandas==0.12.0
Pillow==2.5.3
poster==0.8.1
psycopg2==2.5.4
pybamboo==0.5.8.1
pylibmc==1.3.0
pymongo==2.7.2
python-dateutil==2.6.0
python-digest==1.7
-e git+https://github.com/qlands/python-json2xlsclient.git@5a39387752d819cb6387f75569dbea9a5288aa6f#egg=python_json2xlsclient
pytz==2014.7
-e git+https://github.com/XLSForm/pyxform.git@cfe8589f40319fa3279b0a83e0d23d49bcbe8408#egg=pyxform
recaptcha-client==1.0.6
requests==2.4.1
savReaderWriter==3.4.2
simplejson==2.6.2
six==1.10.0
South==1.0
traceback2==1.4.0
unicodecsv==0.9.4
unittest2==1.1.0
vine==1.1.3
xlrd==0.9.3
xlwt==0.7.5
```

I tried to add set the path and setting in the validate but nothing works.

Any idea what could have changed and how to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The django process doesn't appear to be seeing your formshare.settings.default_settings. Without seeing the project structure, it's hard to know exactly what's going on, but a few things you might check.

- If you are using python 2.x, does the formshare/ and the settings/ directory both have an __init__.py file in them?
- Try adding /opt/formshare/src/ to the python path instead of (or in addition to) what you have.

One trick that I often try to make sure the python path is correct: while I'm active in my virtualenv, I'll enter a python shell (not django shell) and try something like the following:

```
import formshare
from formshare import settings
from fomrmshare.settings import default_settings
```

The error messages that might be generated from those might also help isolate the issue.

Comment: Thanks. That helped me to trace the error to a library that got updated and made the app to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Since you activated virtualenv, you have to do something different. Try `add2virtualenv` in `virtualenvwrapper`.For more info

http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#add2virtualenv